# Function or package to compare model fits side by side?

Tags: r

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
m1 <- lm(price ~ carat, data = diamonds)
m2 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut, data = diamonds)
m3 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut + depth, data = diamonds)

m1r2 <- summary(m1)$r.squared
m2r2 <- summary(m2)$r.squared
m3r2 <- summary(m3)$r.squared

data.frame(
  model = c("m1", "m2", "m3"),
  RSqd = c(m1r2, m2r2, m3r2)
)
```

With caret I often use the following to compare multiple models side by side:

```
resamples(list_of_models) %>% summary()
```

Is there a conventional approach to comparing models on fit such as R.Squared, AIC, RSE? As opposed to crudely writing a dataframe in the way I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `mget`

```
stack(mget(ls(pattern = "^m\\d+r\\d+$")))
```

---

From the input 'm's, get thee objects in to a `list` with `mget` and apply the `summary` by looping over the `list` and extract the `r.squared`

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^m\\d+$")), function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
```

---

Also, this can be done with `reformulate` by passing the independent variables in a `list`

```
lapply(list('carat', c('carat', 'cut'), c('carat', 'cut', 'depth')),
         function(nm) summary(lm(reformulate(nm, 'price'), 
                data = diamonds))$r.squared)
```

---

If we want to get multiple components

```
library(broom)
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^m\\d+$")), glance)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm wondering if there's a solution that might take a list of models and return the evaluation metrics for each?
```some_function_or_package_function(list(m1, m2, m3)) {#do stuff}```
Returns a neat and tidy data frame which I can pass to e.g. `DT::datatable`. Does anything come to mind?

Comment: @DougFir you can use `tidy` or `glance` from `broom` but that is a package function

Comment: @DougFir `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^m\\d+$")), tidy)` or `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^m\\d+$")), glance)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar more tidyverse-based approach.

With only three variables it won't save you much typing, but once you have a two digit number of variables the 'many models approach' is really convenient.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

reg_vars <- c("carat", "cut", "depth")

tibble(id = 1:3) %>% 
  mutate(equ = map(id, ~ reformulate(reg_vars[1:.x], response = "price")),
         mod = map(equ, ~ lm(.x, data = diamonds)),
         res  = map(mod, glance)) %>%
  pull(res) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = "model")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `texreg` package.

```
library(texreg)
screenreg(list(m1, m2, m3))
```